# Kendo MVC DropdownList for Relation in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I have a simple class for database model like this

```
Student.cs
public class Student{
    public long Id; //database generated and key. 
    public string name; //simple name
    public virtual StudentData data; //reference to another data
}

StudentData.cs    
public class StudentData {
    public long Id { get;set; } //database generated and key
    public string CityName {get;set; } //simple and dummy data
}

public ActionResult CityName_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
     IQueryable<City> cities= db.City;
     DataSourceResult result = cities.ToDataSourceResult(request, city =>  new {
     Id = city.Id,
     CityName = city.CityName
     });

     return Json(result);
 }
```

I also have editor template for StudentData

```
StudentDataDropdownList.cshtml
@model MyProj.Models.StudentData
@{ 
    Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Id)
        .DataValueField("Id")
        .DataTextField("CityName")
        .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read("CityName_Read", "City");
        });
}
```

Finally, Create Page for Student (Assuming City master data is already available)

```
@model MyProj.Models.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Student Data</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentData)
            <div class="col-md-5">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentData, "StudentDataDropdownList")                   
            </div>                
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The result is that the Name Textbox is showing but the dropdown that I want to be there is not there. It is like it is not being called. Is there something that I miss?

I would like not to use ViewModel for this data, because all other data except the StudentData is just simple string or long.

Comment: Your `EditorTemplate` should be named `StudentData.cshtml` (i.e. to match the class name) and be in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder. Then in the view just `@Html.EditorFor(m=> m.StudentData)`.

Comment: I can't do that because I have another template for StudentData. That's why I use the overload method EditorFor with custom template name

Comment: Then if its specific to a controller, add it to the `/View/YourController/EditorTemplates` folder

Comment: Which controller? Student controller or City Controller? Student Controller is the one that use editorfor, and CityController is the one that dropdownlitfor read from

Comment: StudentController (the one that generated the view)

Comment: Not working. The dropdown is still not showing

Comment: Are you sure it has the correct name and location? Works fine for me. And I assume you really do have properties (`get; set;`) and not just fields in you models.

Comment: Yes it is not working. Even when I move the Dropdownlistfor directly to Create.cshtml file it is not showing too

Comment: So the real issue is `Kendo().DropDownListFor()`? Do you mean its not rendering anything or its not populating any options?

Comment: It is not rendering anything. Tried simple Kendo().DropdownList().Bind() with simple List of string and it is working

Comment: Try `.DataSource(source => { source.Read(read => { read.Action("CityName_Read", "City"); }) })`

Comment: Still not working. I have added my city Controller function to make it more complete

Comment: You have `.DataTextField("cityName")` but `CityName_Read()` method returns `Name` (not `cityName`)

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo. So I tried to put a break point on city controller read. But it seems the controller is not being called.